# Can I get set password in device administrator?

Tags: android

I just want to ask a question that I can set password in device administrator using new password.But this set password can i get while deactivating device administrator?Please tell me.Thank you.

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. We are not general hardware/software tech support.

Comment: It is a programming question.If I can use my set password then I will implement it in my project. That's why I asked the question.If answer is "YES" you can use set password then how can I use this?

Comment: it'd be incredibly BAD if you could retrieve a password like this. you might be able to get the hashed version, but storing the password in reversible encryption is incredibly insecure/stupid.